# How to assign a value to a pointer that points to NULL

Tags: c++

I have a pointer that points to null, and i want to assign it a value. But if i deference it, I get an error. I have tried this:

```
*nullPointer = value;
```

but like I said, I get an error. How can I do this?. I can't do

```
nullPointer = &value
```

Because later value (it's an object) is deleted and nullPointer would point to invalid memory.

Comment: you mean the *pointer is* NULL?

Comment: A pointer can't point to null. It can *be* a null pointer, which means it doesn't point to anything.  And a declared object can't be deleted as long as its name is visible; it only ceases to exist at the end of its scope.  `&value` is a valid address at the time the assignment `nullPointer = &value;` is executed.  It might become invalid later.

Comment: Read [this](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341) and then tell us what you're trying to accomplish.  And read sections 4 and 5 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/); C pointers are essentially the same as C++ pointers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pointers refer to a location in memory (RAM). When you have a `null pointer` it is pointing to null, meaning that it isn't pointing to location in memory. As long as a pointer is null it can't be used to store any information, as there is no memory backing it up.

To use a null pointer you must first allocate memory and then have the pointer point to that newly allocated memory.

```
*int p = null;    
*p = 10; //this won't work as there is no memory backing up this pointer
p = new int;
*p = 10;
```

Comment: *"You cannot assign a value to a pointer that points to null."* -- Not the best wording.  A pointer cannot point to null; it can *be* null (a null pointer, `NULL`), which, as you say, means it doesn't point to anything.  And you certainly can assign a value to a null pointer; you just can't assign a value to the object it points to.

Answer (score 8):

A pointer must point to a valid object in order to something meaningful and it is your responsibility to make sure that the object it points to remains valid.

If the object it points to is on stack, and becomes invalid once its scope is over You should allocate the object on heap using dynamic memory. There is too little information however to know what you are doing and if you need this here.

```
int *ptr = new int;
*ptr = value;
...
...
delete ptr;
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want a pointer that refers to an object until/unless that object is deleted, at which point it acts roughly like a null pointer again -- i.e., you can at least detect that it doesn't point at anything any more.

If that's the case, you probably want a `weak_ptr` (available in C++11, TR1 and Boost). You use that along with `shared_ptr`s. When the last `shared_ptr` to an object is destroyed, the object itself will also be destroyed. After that, you can detect that the `weak_ptr` doesn't refer to anything any more (the [Boost documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/smart_ptr/weak_ptr.htm), among others, has more details).

Edit: Here's an example from the Boost docs for `weak_ptr`:

```
shared_ptr<int> p(new int(5));
weak_ptr<int> q(p);

// some time later

// this will succeed *only* if at least one other reference to the pointee still exists.
if(shared_ptr<int> r = q.lock())
{
    // use *r
}
```

Comment: How do you detect that a pointer to a deleted object is invalid? Even if you delete the object through that pointer the pointer keeps its value. On some compilers/platforms you may still access the deleted object with the pointer although this is clearly undefined behavior.

Comment: @bjhend: This isn't using raw pointers, but `shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr`. `shared_ptr` maintains a reference count to the pointee object, and deletes it only when the reference count drops to zero. You can't dereference the `weak_ptr` directly -- you have to convert it to a `shared_ptr` first, but that will fail if the pointee has already been deleted.

Comment: OK, I misunderstood your first paragraph as a statement about normal pointers. I now see you only expressed the pointer requirements of the original question which are met by the smart pointers.